# Access to public post on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I get access to public post on Facebook that was created by user who haven't authenticated my application? I mean - I created a user for my application and try to get data with his accessToken to public posts of other random users.
Thank you!

Comment: No, you can not access “random users”, because your app is not allowed to use the global user id with API v2, and you won’t have an app-scoped one unless that “random” user has used your app as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can extract random Users from the Feed that will be available with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=feed&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN
```

Comment: With API v2, your app is not allowed to use global user ids – and you won’t have an app-scoped one either if the user did not use your app already.